# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS takes long time after log in

Tags: 18.04

I am using Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in dual-boot mode.

If I use Windows first and then restart the system, Ubuntu boots normally.

However, if I turn on the computer and select Ubuntu, the login screen is displayed but, after I enter the password, ubuntu-color is displayed and the  desktop doesn't appear.

Comment: Is the problem that booting into Ubuntu takes a long time or that it never gets to the desktop?  The subject line and the body text appear to conflict in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue with 18.4 release. But it's getting a little faster.
It helps when you shutdown, nothing  previously crashed or is is in a wait state. i.e Libre Office is waiting to close and you shutdown. Let Ubuntu shut down itself normally.

TC.